# SqlBulkInserT- Importar planilha Excel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, banco-de-dados, asp.net

tenho uma aplicação em dotnet de importar planilha, porém eu não sei por qual motivo não estou conseguindo inserir as informações no banco de dados. Meu código está abaixo.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

 protected void importar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Carregar e salvar o arquivo
    string excelPath = Server.MapPath("~/Files/") + Path.GetFileName(selecionarArquivo.PostedFile.FileName);
    string conString = string.Empty;
    string extension = Path.GetExtension(selecionarArquivo.PostedFile.FileName);

    //Validação
    //Valida a extensão do arquivo:
    if (Path.GetExtension(selecionarArquivo.FileName) != ".xlsx" && Path.GetExtension(selecionarArquivo.FileName) != ".xls")
    {

    }
    else
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(string), "Erro", "<script>alert('Somente arquivos em excel')</script>");
    }

    conString = string.Format(conString, excelPath);
    using (OleDbConnection excel_con = new OleDbConnection(conString))
    {
        excel_con.Open(); //->>>> Aqui está dando um erro estranho a propriedade connectionstring não foi inicializada.
        string sheet1 = excel_con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null).Rows[6]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
        DataTable dtExcelData = new DataTable();

        //[OPTIONAL]: Recomenda-se, caso contrário, os dados serão considerados como String por padrão.
        dtExcelData.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[] { new DataColumn("Id", typeof(int)), // [] passar o valor do campo da tabela do bd

         // Aqui colocarei o campo da planilha de excel
        new DataColumn("Data de Requisição do Pgto", typeof(DateTime)),
        new DataColumn("NUMERO PROCESSO ANTERIOR",typeof(Int32)),
        new DataColumn("NUMERO JUDICIAL", typeof(Int32)),
        new DataColumn("COMARCA", typeof(string)),
        new DataColumn("VARA", typeof(string)),
        new DataColumn("NOME", typeof(string)),
        new DataColumn("CPF", typeof(Int16)),
        new DataColumn("DEENDERECO", typeof(string)),
        new DataColumn("NUENDERECO", typeof(string)),
        new DataColumn("DECOMPLEMENTO", typeof(string)),
        new DataColumn("DEBAIRRO", typeof(string)),
        new DataColumn("NUCEP", typeof(Int16)),
        new DataColumn("NMMUNICIPIO", typeof(string)),
        new DataColumn("BRUTO", typeof(decimal)),
        new DataColumn("IRPF", typeof(decimal)),
        new DataColumn("Nº SEP", typeof(Int16)),
        new DataColumn("DATA SEP", typeof(DateTime)),
        new DataColumn("DATA DE RECEBIMENTO NA ORIGEM", typeof(DateTime)),
        });

        using (OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM sdpj_import_processo", excel_con))
        {
            oda.Fill(dtExcelData);
        }
        excel_con.Close();

        string consString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(consString))
        {
            using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
            {
                //Define o nome da tabela
                sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "@sdpj_import_processo";
                //[OPTIONAL]: Mapeie as colunas do Excel com a da tabela do banco de dados 
                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Data de Requisição Pgto", "DAT_REQ_PGTO");
                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("NUMERO PROCESSO ANTERIOR", "NUM_PROC_ANTERIOR");
                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("NUMERO JUDICIAL", "NUM_PROC_JUDICIAL");
                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("COMARCA", "DSC_COMARCA");
                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("VARA", "NUM_VARA");
                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("VARANOME", "NME_VARA");
                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("NOME", "NME_INTERESSADO");
                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("CPF", "CPF_CNPJ_INTERESSADO");
                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("DEENDERECO", "DSC_ENDERECO");
                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("NUENDERECO", "NUM_ENDERECO");
                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("NMMUNICIPIO", "NME_MUNICIPIO");
                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("DECOMPLEMENTO", "DSC_DECOMPLEMENTO");
                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("DEBAIRRO", "NME_BAIRRO");
                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("NUCEP", "NUM_CEP");
                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("NMMUNICIPIO", "NME_MUNICIPIO");
                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("BRUTO", "VLR_BRUTO");
                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("IRPF", "VLR_IR");
                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("LIQUIDO", "VLR_LIQUIDO");
                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Nº SEP", "COD_SEP");
                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("DATA SEP", "DAT_SEP");
                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("DATA DE RECEBIMENTO NA ORIGEM", "DAT_RECEB_ORIGEM");
                con.Open();
                sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dtExcelData);
                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Está gerando alguma exceção ?

Comment: rLinhares a Mensagem que dá é: Erro de Servidor no Aplicativo '/'.

A propriedade ConnectionString não foi inicializada.

Descrição: Ocorreu uma exceção sem tratamento durante a execução da atual solicitação da Web. Examine o rastreamento de pilha para obter mais informações sobre o erro e onde foi originado no código. 

Detalhes da Exceção: System.InvalidOperationException: A propriedade ConnectionString não foi inicializada.

Comment: Você iniciou a variável `conString` vazia, depois tentou formatá-la, e depois ainda tentou iniciar um `OleDbConnection` com ela ainda vazia, então o erro me parece claro. Atribua uma string de conexão válida para a variável.

Comment: Amigo, você poderia me dá um exemplo, eu não entendi.

Comment: @Amaral, a sua variável `constr` na primeira parte da leitura do excel você não atribui nenhum valor para ela e depois no bulk copy, você verificou se ela está de fato declarada no seu arquivo de configurações na chave `"constr"`?

Comment: Vai no site <a href="https://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/">connectionstrings.com</a> e pega uma string de conexão válida, altera para a sua necessidade e seta na variável `consString`, assim por exempo: `conString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + excelPath`